# Can not do anything with GitHub remotely

Tags: macos, git, github, macos-mojave

Now, my version is 10.14.3 Beta (18D32a).

Since I updated the previous version, As long as I run git clone or git push command, it will lead to:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repository.git/': SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

No matter which repository is the same, and I also tried it with the GitHub Desktop client.

I also tried using SSH to clone a repository, and I got the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This really makes me exhausted, How to fix it? or is there any other way I can use github remotely?

Comment: I presume you have already reported this via the Feedback Assistant?

Comment: yep, and I wanna know is there anyone the same?